# How to create dynamic design dojo with data?

Tags: dojo

hi everyone i'm a newbie in dojo mobile,i want create some thing like this image but dynamic with data by code.How i can do this ? thanks for any help
[image]

Comment: Who can give me some example,please ?....

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the series of tutorials on Tweetview. The first one is here : http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/mobile/tweetview/getting_started/

The subsequent ones are linked at the bottom of that page.

Comment: I've read that,but can you send me some tutorial about load desgin dojo by data or example ?

Comment: There are several ways of doing this... one of them is using dojo stores. See https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2011/02/15/dojo-object-stores/